# Polygon union in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query, geospatial

I have DB that contain polygons, some of which intersect. Is there any way to get a union of all polygons in MongoDB (something like ST_Union in Postgis or Spatialite)?

Thanks,
      Anna

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell MongoDB has yet to support unions in 3.2, which is the latest version as of this writing.

Here's a list of the operations that are supported:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query-geospatial/